# Next.js принцип поведения страниц и контроллеров

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nextjs, next.js

Всем привет! Работаю с Next.js совсем чуть-чуть. И я не нашел статейки которая объяснила бы всю структуру приложений на Next. Одни сплошные "давайте создадим блог". У меня ситуация когда бэк у меня готов в виде api а next-app должен всего-лишь кидать запрос, принимать ответ, отображать данные.

Покажу страницу моей авторизации XD да-да, я знаю она ужасна =)

```js
import { Component } from 'react'
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch'
import { auth } from '../../utils/auth'

class Login extends Component {
  static getInitialProps({ req }) {
    const protocol = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'https' : 'http'
    const host = `localhost:3001`
    const apiUrl =  `${protocol}://${host}/admin/account/login`
    return { apiUrl }
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      code: '',
      preToken: '',
      isPreAuth: true,
      isAuth: false,
      isLoad: false,
      error: ''
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    console.log({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value })
  }

  async handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    try {
      let response;
      this.setState({ error: '', isLoad: true })
      if (this.state.isPreAuth) {
        response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/admin/account/login`, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
          body: new URLSearchParams(`email=${this.state.email}&password=${this.state.password}`)
        })
      } else {
        response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/admin/account/token`, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
          body: new URLSearchParams(`preToken=${this.state.preToken}&code=${this.state.code}`)
        })
      }
      if (response.ok) {
        const request = await response.json()
        const token = request.values.token;
        auth({ token })
        this.setState({ isAuth: true, isPreAuth: false, isLoad: false, preToken: token })
      } else {
        console.log('Login failed.')
        this.setState({ error: 'Login failed.', isLoad: false })
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(
        'You have an error in your code or there are Network issues.',
        error
      )
      throw new Error(error)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div id="login_container">
          <div id="login_block">

            {this.state.isLoad &&
              <span id="loader"><i className="loading_a"></i></span>}

            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="auth">

              {this.state.isPreAuth &&
                <input
                  type='email'
                  id='email'
                  name='email'
                  placeholder="Имя аккаунта"
                  value={this.state.username}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />}

              {this.state.isPreAuth &&
                <input
                  type='password'
                  id='password'
                  name='password'
                  placeholder="Пароль"
                  value={this.state.password}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
              }

              {this.state.isAuth &&
                <input
                  type='text'
                  id='code'
                  name='code'
                  placeholder="PIN код"
                  value={this.state.code}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
              }

              <div className="login_control">
                <button type='submit'>Login</button>
                <p className={`error ${this.state.error && 'show'}`}>
                  {this.state.error && `Error: ${this.state.error}`}
                </p>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <style jsx>{`
#login_container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#login_block {
    display: block;
    width: 20rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 1px rgb(216, 216, 216);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 1px rgb(216, 216, 216);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 1px rgb(216, 216, 216);
}

.auth {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

input {
    width: 270px;
    margin: 10px 25px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
    height: 35px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.login_control {
    margin: 10px 25px;
}

button {
    padding: 7px 16px 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 20px;
    background-color: #3f8cb5;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

p {
  display: inline;
    line-height: 35px;
    margin-left: 25px;
}


#loader {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ffffffc7;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.loading_a {
  animation: rotation 1s infinite linear;
  border: 1px solid rgba(156, 156, 156, 0.2);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top-color: rgba(58, 58, 58, 0.7);
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
}

@keyframes rotation {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

        `}</style>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default Login
```

по факту тут есть 2 стадии страницы login.

1. Ввод логина и пароля, получение предварительного токена ( api в этот момент отправляет пин код для входа на почту ).
2. После получения предварительного токена поля логина и пароля меняется на поле для пина. и при нажатии на ту же кнопку отправляется запрос на другой адрес api.

Я подумал что 2 формы ( логин и пасс / пин код ) вывести стоит в компоненты. Но тут еще больше вопросов. Как страница login должна понимать что предварительный токен получен и пора вывести вторую форму.

Вообщем я понимаю что четкого вопроса сформулировать тут не получается... Буду благодарен за указания на ошибки и подсказки по реализации правильных приложений на react

Comment: 1. "благодарен за ... подсказки по реализации ... на react" - т.е. у вас, вопрос по реакту а не по nextjs?
2. Вы не реализуете api средствами nextjs? (или они стороннее)
3. Ваш вопрос выглядит как: "Как реализовать авторизацию с помощью реакт?"
4. Возможно вам не понятно какая часть реакт отработает на сервере а какая на клиенте и ваш вопрос именно в этом?

Comment: api работает на fastify. Реализация авторизации уже есть. Она успешно проходит, но код который я указал кажется мне не корректным.

Comment: https://auth0.com/blog/next-js-authentication-tutorial  
"Next, you will create a file called _document.js inside src/pages and add the following code to it:"

Comment: `_document.js` - https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document  
"Document is only rendered in the server, event handlers like `onClick` won't work"

Comment: сама же авторизация - "Building custom APIs with Next.js" - (thoughts-api) это БЭК, экспресс

Answer (score 0):

Переходите на реакт-хуки, они проще.

```
const [send, setSend] = useState(false)

const sendForm = () => {
   // отправляем форму
   setSend(true) // Теперь страница знает что форма была отправлена
}

return (
 <div>
   {!send && <div>форма логина</div>} // отображается если форма не была отправлена
   {send && <div>форма ввода токена с почты</div>} // наоборот

 </div>
)
```

Comment: Я их и использую как вы могли бы заметить в примере который я предоставил

Comment: @АртурФранк нет, вы используете классы.